# Bookdown book displayed from within a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bookdown

I am trying to use bookdown to write a user manual for a Shiny app.  I can link the index.html page into the shy app, but that is the only page that displays.  The book does not appear.  it is in the gitbook format so I should have the outline on the left and the book on the right.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Okay:  Here is the Server code creates the object to be used in the UI:    
output$helpFile <- renderUI({
  includeHTML("C:/Users/jch1748/Documents/Projects/W2012005 - Develop Understanding of Verification Risk/ShinyIntDev/Manual/Demo/_book/index.html")
})

Comment: Okay:  Here is the code creates the object to be used in the UI: 
   
tabPanel("Help Notes",
         includeHTML("C:/Users/jch1748/Documents/Projects/W2012005 - Develop Understanding of Verification Risk/ShinyIntDev/Manual/Demo/_book/index.html")


Beyond this do you need the book file to be able to reproduce?  I cannot share the book, it contains company proprietary information

Comment: I cannot get that to format correctly, sorry.